# Format Python String - messagebox:tkinter

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, tkinter, messagebox

I would like `This is a help message:` in the following string to be displayed in **bold**.

```
help_message = """This is a help message:
 Demo!"""

tk.messagebox.showinfo('Help', help_message)
```

Can this be done with `"""{}content""".format('some_style_string')`?

---

I have seen other examples use code like the following:

```
class color:
    PURPLE = '\033[95m'
    CYAN = '\033[96m'
    DARKCYAN = '\033[36m'
    BLUE = '\033[94m'
    GREEN = '\033[92m'
    YELLOW = '\033[93m'
    RED = '\033[91m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
    END = '\033[0m'
```

But all the examples seem to involve the use of print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can this be done with """{}content""".format('some_style_string')

No, it cannot. `tk.messagebox` cannot show styled text.

> I have seen other examples use code like the following...

No, that won't work either. Those are escape codes that are designed to be interpreted by an ansi terminal (or by the `curses` package).

If you want styled text then you will have to create your own dialog with `Toplevel` and some text, label, or canvas widgets.

Comment: other examples show 'master.option_add('*Dialog.msg.font', 'Helvetica 12')', is syntax this possible? and I haven't really mastered class design with python/tkinter as yet, do you have a good generic messagebox (toplevel) example?

Comment: @10SecTom: examples are just a google search away.  Here's one: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm